# How to add gradle dependency automatically

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, dependencies

I'm wondering if there is any gradle task or any other util that will **add dependency** so e.g.

```
dependencies {
   ... // so far dependencies    
   compile 'com.new.dependency:x.y"
}
```

in your **build.gradle** file instead you manually type it.

I'm trying to write IntelliJ plugin that will automatically add a library to any project. So far I need to analyze/parse document content and it's tedious.

For example when you go to project setting in IntelliJ and add library the code is automatically added.

Comment: I'm looking for something what Crashlytics introduced in their Android Studio plugin. It adds a new line in build.dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify collections as your dependencies, like:

```
dependencies {
   compile ['org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5','org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1']
}
```

Which means you can use anything that can produce a list.  If your plugin maintained a file like:

***compile.dependencies:***

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
```

Then you could include the dependencies into the project like:

```
dependencies {   
    compile file('compile.dependencies').readLines()
}
```

Users of your plugin would have to know to add these lines to their build.gradle. Or, better, you could bundle the configuration into an include file, like:

```
subprojects() {
  dependencies {   
     if (file('compile.dependencies').exists()) {
       compile file('compile.dependencies').readLines()
     }

     if (file('runtime.dependencies').exists()) {
      runtime file('runtime.dependencies').readLines()
     }
  }
}
```

Then your users would only have to use "apply from:" to include the config.

Comment: I'm trying to create a plugin so user does nothing and it's my plugin which edits the build.gradle file. I'm looking for sth like Crashlytics plugin does.

Comment: Well, your plugin or user can add a single "apply from:" line to include the configuration, or you can try to parse/update the build.gradle file. IMO the latter is hopeless given the variety of ways which gradle dependencies can be specified.

Comment: @DaveSmith where to keep the file compile.dependencies. should I specify full path?

Comment: @Adi, in this example, the file() method resolves relative to the current project or subproject.   So you would place them in the project or subproject  path.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such tool, nor utility. There's a possibility to add dependencies to project using [tooling API](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/embedding.html) but the changes introduced will not be serialized to configuration (build.gradle) file.