# Generate android gradle dependency using intelliJ idea plugin

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am try to write a IntelliJ plugin that will automatically add dependency to android build.gradle file.

```
 dependencies {
 compile com.XXX.XX }
```

For example when we add Crashlytics plugin in android studio.
 its adds a dependency in build.gradle file. I need the exact solution for my plugin. I refer the below link

[How to add gradle dependency automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161892/how-to-add-gradle-dependency-automatically)

Kindly give more idea to implement this.